# MBA & VGA monitor, using strange reduction Thunderbolt-HDMI-DVI-VGA

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport, dvi, vga-adapter

I have latest Macbook Air and I want try to use VGA monitor. I don't have MiniDisplayPort to VGA reduction, but this:
[image: Thunderbolt-HDMI-DVI-VGA]

I know that DVI-VGA worked fine on with my old PC, so I don't understand, why doesn't work the HDMI-DVI?

**EDIT:**
 I tried the white adapter with HDMI cable and monitor and I doesn't work the same way. The MBA knows about monitor, but the monitor is without signal..

Answer (score 1):

The Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter does not pass analog signal, only digital.  VGA is analog.